# An isometry between totally geodesic submanifolds is smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

I am studying Sharafutdinov's *Convex sets in a manifold on nonnegative curvature*.

I have found the following statement, $S_0$ being a totally geodesic submanifold of an open Riemannian variety $M$ and $h_t$ a map from $S_0$ onto $S_t$ that respects the Riemannian distance (i.e. a metric isometry of $S_0$ onto $S_t$).

> Since $S_0$ is a totally geodesic submanifold and $h_t$ is an isometry of $S_0$ onto $S_t$, it follows easily that $S_t$ is a totally geodesic submanifold in $M$ and the mapping $h_t$ is smooth.

I have trouble in understanding why is true. How precisely do I convert a statement on distances (the fact that $h_t$ is a metric isometry) in the fact that $S_t$ is also a submanifold?

EDIT: The part that $h_t$ is smooth follows then from Myers-Steenrod.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe we can start with showing that the image of a geodesic is a geodesic.

Comment: This I think I can do. I still fail to see how this tells us something about the differential structure, sorry...

Comment: How about using the exponential map on $S_0$ and $S_t$? We have the mapping of geodesics to geodesics and from the tangent spaces to these manifolds

Comment: I have followed your suggestion. Does the following work? Consider $p\in S_0$ and neighbourhoods around $p$ and $h_t(p)$ such that the two restricted exponential maps are diffeomorphisms. Now build a map $T_pS_0\to T_{h(p)}S_t$ as $H(\lambda v)=\lambda exp_{h_t(p)}^{-1}(h_t(exp_p(v))$ where $v$ is sufficiently small to allow $exp_p$ to be a diffeomorphism. I claim that $H$ is linear, due to the fact that geodesics go into geodesics: is this true?

Comment: I can see that $H$ is norm preserving but can't quite see why it is linear.

Comment: You are right, there is no reason for $H$ to be linear. Any other hints to solve the problem?

Comment: Some useful ideas here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294483/how-to-prove-the-distance-isometry-is-a-smooth-on-a-riemannian-manifold

Comment: That helped. In fact, I had just forgotten Myers-Steenrod theorem. The only point I am missing now is that I don't know that $S_t$ is smooth (which MS theorem assumes). But I know that geodesics go into geodesics, so... could I say that the differentiable structure on the image is given by charts of the form $\phi\circ h_t^{-1}$ around $h_t(p)$, where $\phi$ are distance coordinates on $S_0$? (I.e., coordinates given by the $n$-uple $\phi=(dist(q_i,\cdot))$ where $q_i=\exp_{p}(\epsilon e_i)$ where $\epsilon$ is small and $e_i$ form an orthonormal basis of the tangent space at $S_0$ in $p$.)