# $\lim_{t \to 0} \left( \frac{d_g(\mathrm{exp}_p(tv), \mathrm{exp}_p(tw))}{t} \right) = |v - w|_g$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

> Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian $n$-manifold and let $p \in M$. Show that, for $v, w \in T_pM$, we have $$\lim_{t \to 0} \left( \frac{d_g(\mathrm{exp}_p(tv), \mathrm{exp}_p(tw))}{t} \right) = |v - w|_{g_p},$$ where $d_g$ is the distance induced by the metric $g$.

I am not sure how to prove this. I am given the hint that I should use the Taylor expansion of $g$ in Riemannian normal coordinates.

In Riemannian normal coordinates $(U, (x^1, \cdots, x^n))$, denoting by $g_{ij}$ the components of the metric $g$, we have that $p = 0$, $$g_{ij}(0) = \delta_{ij} $$ and $$\partial_k g_{ij}(0) = 0. $$

Hence, Taylor expanding each function $g_{ij}$ around $0$, we get that $$g_{ij}(x) = \delta_{ij} + \sum_{k, l = 1}^n x^k x^l \partial_{kl} g_{ij}(0) + O(|x|^3). $$

Moreover, for small $t$, in these coordaintes,  $$\mathrm{exp}_p(tv) = tv \text{ and } \mathrm{exp}_p(tw) = tw. $$

However, how can we compute $d_g(\mathrm{exp}_p(tv), \mathrm{exp}_p(tw))$?

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486882/a-lemma-for-proving-myers-steenrod-theorem?noredirect=1)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!